# How to use bindings with RoboVM and LibGDX?

Tags: android, binding, libgdx, robovm

I want to add adMob and Google Play Game Services to my app for iOS and android. I know I can do this using bindings. I have been searching online and that is what I have found. However, being new to programming, I cannot find a clear cut tutorial on how to use this, I do not know what a binding is nor how to install RoboVM or what it is. Would anyone be able to help me out on how to use RoboVM to accomplish this with simple and easy to follow steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RoboVM is deprecated in favor of RoboPods.

https://github.com/robovm/robovm-robopods/tree/master

Follow the instructions on the site, just add the line of code for the jar you want to include. Add the link under iOS section of your build.gradle located in your project directory.

Then just refresh Gradle. For eclipse, right click project, gradle>refresh all. You now have the jar in your Gradle Dependencies. Now you're just missing the code to show Admob ads and Google Play Game Services.

Comment: wow, thanks. It says it is for iOS only, how would I use it for android using LibGDX?

Comment: Yes, roboVM with RoboPods is used for iOS while google play services is used for android. Different devices, different code. For android, after integrating the android sdk to your IDE, just link the google play services lib to the android project.